# what size of copper wire can act as a 150A fuse?

Tags: current, wire, wiring, fuses

If I would like to use a piece of copper wire as a 150A fuse, what size of wire should I use?

It doesn't have to be 150A very accurately, the parameters I need the wire to meet are:

- it needs to conduct continuously 70A 10V-30V DC without getting red or overheating
- it needs to conduct 120A sometimes for 15 seconds without melting
- it needs to surely be melted before the current reaches 200A

Easily available wires over here are: 0.5 mm^2, 0.75 mm^2, 1.0 mm^2, 1.5 mm^2, 2.5 mm^2, 4 mm^2, 6 mm^2, 10 mm^2. Will any of these do the job? I can combine a few if the required value is not in the above series.

---

Edit: now I read more into the specifications of the device, and it is in fact rated to be fine with 600A for 5 seconds. Besides that I will be only ever using it continuously with 50A. Is that gap (50A - 600A) large enough to make a fuse out of copper?

[This table of AWG wire sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Table_of_AWG_wire_sizes) suggests that a 2.5mm^2 copper wire will melt with about 750A in 1s, and with a little under 200A in 10s, so it looks like it will melt in time for the device not to be damaged. The device itself is wired with 10mm^2 insulated wire, and I mostly worry about that wire not to be damaged.

Now I only need to find out to what temperature will a short piece of uninsulated 2.5mm^2 copper wire heat-up with 50A continuous current flow, and will it not melt the thing it is secured in at that temperature.

By "continuous" use I mean max 1 hour at a time, with full attendance of me, so it will not run unattended like this.

---

More info: The machine came originally with two 50A fuses wired in parallel. In fact I want to use a wire, because the fuses blow so often it starts to get expensive, on average I need 1 fuse per 1 hour of charging, so the fuses cost more then the electricity to power this. I don't know why they blow, because I have an ammeter wired in series with the fuse, and I never seen anything over 60A on the ammeter! The fuses don't blow randomly, I just can see the fuse slowly get red, it stays red for some time, and at one point it just melts. I've been watching this process and I didn't see over 60A while the fuse was melting, I was watching the ammeter all the time in the slow process of the fuse being melted. So if I need 1 fuse per hour, so be it, but I need some cheaper option then 50 cents a fuse if I am to use them at that rate.

Comment: It sounds like you want something that behaves like a [fusible link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusible_link).  Any reason you wouldn't just use / build a fusible link?

Comment: @miernik, the reason we purchase fuses is so that a fault event is *quickly* interrupted, you need to make sure copper will flash off fast enough to protect your load/source.

Comment: @miernik, why not a fuse? As Kortuk states, that's the safety function they perform. Wire...dodgy at best and it will not breakdown fast or reliably enough IMO.

Comment: Because if I am far away from any shop which carries suitable fuses, and I need a solution working now, I need something out of the material I have, which will at least be better then wiring the thing with a thick wire without any fuse, so I am looking for the most suitable wire if copper wire is the only thing I've got. Assume you are on a dessert, far from shops with fuses, you have only wires, and not running the device until you get a proper fuse is not an option. What size wire you would use?

Comment: If I was on a dessert, and it was so big that there wasn't a place I could get a fuse nearby, I would start eating it, and not worry about electronics for a while!

Comment: I believe that you won't be able to attain the specs you wrote with just a simple copper wire (you would need a more complicated geometry and materials for it to blow fast and reliably)

Comment: pretty sure i saw a macgyver episode once where he used a bubble gum wrapper in place of a fuse in a three phase power switch.  Give it a try! (please don't)

Comment: I think you should look at why the fuses are blowing since they are supposed to be OK. Are you sure that your ammeter is reading correctly (e.g. AC vs. DC, high-frequency variation, ...)? Are both fuseholders actually in the circuit (does only one of the fuses ever blow)?

Comment: Kevin: this is DC, the ammeter is a LY5135A-2 with a 200A range which is actually a 75mV voltmeter over a 0.375 mOhm shunt, and the two 50A fuses where two flat pieces of some metal on top of each other, touching each other with full surface, of course they both melt.

Comment: Do fuses ever blow to the extent that the melting generates a plasma, that then conducts better than the wire itself?

Comment: > 1 kviews and only 1 upvote. Interesting.

Comment: Don't use copper. It's thermal conductivity is too high, and as a result, everything near the pseudo-fuse will get hot when you approach the fusing voltage. Something like steel or another metal with poor thermal conductivity will work much better.

Comment: two 50A fuses wired in parallel sounds like the source of your frequently blown fuses - why are they in parallel? why not a single 100A fuse? (100A is a fairly common fuse size in the automotive industry, I would imagine others as well)

Comment: You see 60A through a 50A fuse and you're wondering why it slowly melts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finding a fuse with those characteristics is going to be difficult. I'd use a current shunt with a suitable MCU and circuit breaker and monitor the current taken by the device, shutting off the current if it rises above 120A for 15 seconds.

Two fuses in parallel can cause problems unless they are well-matched and the holders are properly designed. Any difference between them can cause one fuse to take more current than the other one, and fail.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds to me like like you're about to violate some NEC/NFPA* fire and safety regulations. Replacing a fuse like this with bare copper wire is **ILLEGAL** period. Machine downtime is always preferable to property damage, injury or loss of life.

EDIT * Assuming you're in the USA.

Comment: Well, but a fuse is just a piece of wire. OK, its probably something else then copper, but still its just a wire, just of the right size to melt at the right current. Fuses are not God-given and do not fall from the the sky as miraculously self-created objects from a secret source - no, they are made by humans, out of some wire. So I am asking "how to make a 150A fuse".

Comment: @miernik, how to make a 150A fuse and how to make one from copper are different, you are asking something more specialized. @chris is worried you are going to violate laws or safety. Copper is not ideal as it will not enter thermal runaway as well as devices design for this. Manufacturing fuses is still quite a bit of work.

Comment: make sure you put a glass or ceramic envelope around your copper wire.  Copper melts at 1085 °C and I have scars to prove it.  There will almost certainly be a fire if anything flammable is near your melted wire, or underneath where the molten copper splatters.

Comment: @miernik I guess I'm really just concerned about your application. If this if for home, hobby, prototyping some fuse design then cool. However your comment _"I've got. Assume you are on a dessert, far from shops with fuses, you have only wires, and not running the device until you get a proper fuse is not an option. What size wire you would use?"_

Comment: -continued from above- (for some reason my edit did not take)

Coupled with that fact that this is for 150A set off a red flag in my head (probably because I work in a factory setting). If you're building this for home, hobby, or prototyping a fuse design then cool, my bad. If however you're looking for a quick fix for a blown fuse on a piece of equipment in a commercial or industrial setting then I stand by my legal/safety concerns.

Comment: This is for hobby, for charging some batteries. The story about the desert was just to try to keep the answers in the scope of the question - fuse from copper wire.

Comment: The key difference between wire and fuses is that fuses are designed to fail above a specified current, whereas wire is designed to work up to a specified current. *These are not the same thing.* A copper wire will likely work well past its "rated" current, with a large tolerance in current levels at which it fails. The fail-open current for a fuse, while not perfect, is much better controlled, and as others have pointed out, will not create as much of a fire hazard due to the lower melting point of the non-copper (aluminum?) material.

Answer (score 6):

Forget trying to design your own fuse, leave that to experts whose livelihood depends on safe and accurate designs.  Call a fuse manufacturer's technical department and discuss the parameters that you provided on your load (600A 5 secs maximum, 50A continuous).
Fuses protect the load AND the cable feeding the load.  Replace your parallel fuse holders with one fuse that is designed for purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Fuses don't work well in parallel, especially if they are installed in mechanical holders and not soldered. Holder terminals inevitably oxidize, which increases the resistance and affects current distribution.

Now, if there's a single fuse, oxidation doesn't become an issue. Increased resistance results in voltage drop in oxide layer which gets destroyed, restoring the contact.

That doesn't happen if you have a second fuse in parallel: that fuse will shunt the high resistance spot and let the oxide on the other fuse grow. Eventually, the oxide layer will completely isolate one of the fuses, forcing all the current through the other fuse and destroying it.

So, get a single 100A fuse. If you can't, try soldering two 50A fuses to the terminals. Also make sure that each fuse has a significant (and roughly equal) length of wire before the joint: wire resistance will help to equalize the current in both fuses:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFstz3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It should be noted that R1 and R2 should be rated for 25 W, of course with some derating.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're planning ahead for a tragedy.  Kinda like, "If a robber comes through the door should I shoot him, or stab him?"  Forget that and just lock the door!  :)

What you should do with all your planning is simply buy extra fuses and keep them handy.  If on the odd chance that you run out of fuses, then kludge something up however the situation calls for it (keeping in mind the safety and legal aspects of it).  But at that point, you're not worrying about what amperage the copper wire is going to melt.

Comment: No, strike that, don't kludge anything up!  This is 150A we're talking about here.

Comment: I once used a bunch of "wire fuses" in series with a "normal fuse" when experimenting with a motor-control project.  I had a bunch of turns of wire wrapped around one post, which then went to a second post which had a few wires were wrapped around.  Each time the thing blew, I could simply unwrap some more turns from the first post and connect to the second.  The wire let through enough current for operation, but consistently blew before the normal fuse.  Not something I'd do in an unattended device, but the wire was probably cheaper than replacing the fuse a few dozen times would have been.

Answer (score 2):

Fusible links in automotive use are normally made with a short length of wire (25-35 mm) that is two wire gauge sizes smaller than the wire supplying the load.  For example, if the wire is 12 AWG, use 14 AWG wire for the fusible link.  (Convert American Wire Gauge, AWG, to whatever system of measurement you are using in your part of the world.)  This will prevent a fire that destroys the vehicle, but the wiring in the system may still overheat and be permanently damaged.

If super-fast response is not required, consider replacing the fuses with an appropriately rated thermal circuit breaker.  A thermal-magnetic circuit breaker, such as those used in house wiring, can be used for faster response to overloads.  You may find that replacing the fuses two or three times costs more than the circuit breaker and its enclosure.